#  Disable tooltip function on hover but value stays

Tags: php, html, tooltip

I have this problem regarding my project. it contains images used as links where it has the attribute "title".

What I want to do is to disable the tooltip function which displays the value inside "title" attribute. but, the catch here is that i don't want to completely remove the value inside "title" because i need it for my jquery fancybox function.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: You should mention your programming language and what framework you are using.

Comment: try removing the `alt` attribute from the `<img>` tag

Comment: @Alpine i don't have any alt attribute.

Comment: .This is my link image code.

<a id="various3" href="picture.php" title="<?php echo $info; ?>">

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to your question

[Removing Tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419797/removing-tooltip)

Comment: .I already read the link that you gave me, it's still not enough because the code that was given there would only solve my first problem which is to remove the tooltip display on hover. but at the same time it also removes the value and there is no following code that would restore it.

Comment: You could write a javascript code to implement it, like `onmouseover` call `removeTitle()` and on `mouseout` call `restoreTitle()`

Comment: .I can't seem to find the correct javascript code for the function removeTitle() and restoreTitle.